# Extra column in raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, convert, arcgis-10.4

I have converted a polygon file to raster (ArcMap 10.4), after setting extent and cell size environments to match my DEM (which is also set as snap raster). On the new raster, the extents are the same as the DEM *EXCEPT* for the right (top, bottom and left match). The new raster has one more column than DEM, which prevents me from using it in the model I want to use.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Never mind! I fixed it by using extraction tool (by rectangle; the extent of the DEM) on the newer raster. Now, the newest output raster and the DEM have identical extent, columns and rows.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  Would you be able to please [edit] your answer to expand on the steps you followed to solve the problem?  That way users with the same question in the future can find the answer here.